# How to customize the shake animation in IOS's UIImageView

Tags: ios, image, animation, shake

I'm coding a shake image function, and the code is below:

```
CABasicAnimation* shake = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
shake.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:-0.2];
shake.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:+0.2];
shake.duration = 0.1;
shake.autoreverses = YES; 
shake.repeatCount = 4;
[self.imageView.layer addAnimation:shake forKey:@"imageView"];
self.imageView.alpha = 1.0;
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:2.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:nil completion:nil];
```

I have two questions:

1.the code above will shake the image around its center(transform.rotation.z).But how to make the image shake around the bottom center?

2.How can I control the start and stop of this shaking animation? For example, make the image shaking until get data from server finished then stop the animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do this by modifying the image. Make it twice as tall but have the bottom just be transparent.

A similar solution that only uses code:
Put the `ImageView` into another view...call it `imageHolderView` where `imageHolderView` is twice as tall as the image, but it otherwise just transparent, and then shake *that* instead of just your image